# Jasmine TypeScript unit test fails if types in methods being tested are not fully qualified

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

So I have successfully got unit testing working with my angularjs app using Jasmine and Karma. However, I've just hit an annoying issue I can't figure out.

So I have a controller with a very simple method like this (this is a random example so don't worry if it seems weird):

```
public ExecuteUserCreatedCommand(
  id: number,
  userId: string) {
  const command = new Commands.UserCreated();
  command.Id = id;
  command.userId = userId;

  return this.CommandService.UserCreated(command);
}
```

Note that the Commands.UserCreated object is defined in another file and its fully qualified name is:

```
Application.Commands.UserCreated
```

Now I don't need to use the Application namespace in the application as the controller is in it too.

However, my unit test which looks a bit like this (I've hacked it a bit for the purposes of this post so don't worry about it being perfect):

```
it("should send a command to create a new user", () => {

const userCreatedCommand = new Application.Commands.UserCreated();
userCreatedCommand.Id = 1;
userCreatedCommand.UserId = "ab0277a9-79ba-4240-82cf-072444103e6c";

spyOn(commandService, "UserCreated");

MainController.ExecuteUserCreatedCommand(1, "ab0277a9-79ba-4240-82cf-072444103e6c");
expect(commandService.UserCreated).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userCreatedCommand );});
```

Now this will fail before whilst executing:

```
MainController.ExecuteUserCreatedCommand(...)
```

With the error:

> ReferenceError: Commands is not defined

But if I change the method being called so it has this line instead it passes fine:

```
const command = new Application.Commands.UserCreated();
```

I can kind of see why this might be the case but I don't know how to properly solve it without changing all of my methods to have fully qualified object types!

Comment: That does not seem likely. `namespace`s don't work that way.

Comment: It does seems really strange after a bit more investigation because the, as expected, the JavaScript creates the right functions for each part of the namespace (if the name is fully qualified or not) so it should be recognised.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with `spyOn` how it proxies the object being tested? If so, I would advise against using it since that seems strange and magical...

Comment: Maybe but I didn't think it would be that because the code fails before the expects.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you never call pass `userCreatedCommand` to the method.

Comment: Good shout, I've edited the question